# Proper way of passing a primitive argument with an NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I'm using a basic timer that calls this method:

```
- (void) refresh:(id)obj
{
    if (obj == YES) doSomething;
}
```

I want to call this method from certain areas of my code and also from a timer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:refreshInterval
                            target:self
                            selector:@selector(refresh:) 
                            userInfo:nil 
                            repeats:YES];
```

When I put `YES` as the argument for the `userInfo` parameter, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error; why is this?

Can someone help me do this the right way so that there is no ugly casting and such?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `userInfo` parameter must be an object; it is typed `id`. `YES` is a primitive, namely the value `1`. In order to make sure the `userInfo` object does not get deallocated, the timer retains it. So, when you passed `YES`, NSTimer was doing `[(id)YES retain]`. Try that in your own code and see what happens. :-P

As the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) states, the selector you give the method must have the signature

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
```

This means you can't have an NSTimer invoke just any method—not directly at least. You can make a special method with the above signature which in turn invokes any method you want though.

So, say you have a method called `refresh:`, and you want to call it every so often, passing it `YES`. You can do this like so:

```
// somewhere
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:refreshInterval
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(invokeRefresh:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void)invokeRefresh:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self refresh:YES];
}

- (void)refresh:(BOOL)flag {
    if (flag) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Objective-C, a primitive type is not an object. So you can't directly pass it to an argument which expects an `id`, which stands for a generic object. You need to wrap it into an `NSNumber` object.

Use

```
NSTimer*timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:refreshInterval
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(refresh:) 
                               userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                                repeats:YES];
```

and

```
- (void) refresh:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    NSNumber* shouldDoSomething=[timer userInfo];
    if ([shouldDoSomething boolValue]) doSomething;
}
```

Don't forget to invalidate and release the timer once it's done.

By the way, you don't have to compare a `BOOL` (or C++ `bool`) against `YES` or `true` or whatever. When you write

```
if(a>b) { ... }
```

`a>b` evaluates to a bool, and `if` uses the result. What you're doing there is like

```
if((a>b)==YES) { ... }
```

which is quite strange to me. It's not that the `(..)` after `if` should contain a comparison; it should contain a bool.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to kperryua's answer, if you want to pass a primitive through userInfo you can box it with `NSNumber` or `NSValue`; in the case of a boolean, you'd want to use `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`, then call `boolValue` in the timer callback to get back the primitive.