# Pass integer in userInfo of NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, nsinteger

I'm trying to pass an integer (`testInt`) through the `userInfo` field of `NSTimer`

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(count:) userInfo:testInt repeats:YES];
```

However I'm getting an incompatible types error message.

Does anyone know how to pass a number through to the `count` method?

Comment: `userInfo` is supposed to be an object.

Comment: [Proper way of passing a primitive argument with an NSTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3262268)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to box it to an [NSNumber](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(count:) 
                                       userInfo:@(testInt)  // <-- @() around your int.
                                        repeats:YES];
```

Then in `-count:`

```
int testInt = [timer.userInfo intValue];
```